# Why does Android Studio generated OnFragmentInteractionListener method pass a Uri object?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Creating a new Fragment in Android Studio creates an Interface like this:

```
/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

This is useful for communicating from Fragment to Activity. Defining an implementing this interface is also described as the usual way to [Creating event callbacks to the activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) within the official [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) documentation.

But what I don't understand is why a Uri object is passed. I know I can define and implement the interface as I want to. But is there any special reason to pass a Uri object and nothing else?

Comment: I've never used this pattern. I don't know why the Android team decided a Uri is the most appropriate default here. Of course, you can always change the parameter to whatever best fits your needs.

Comment: (Just a guess) Probably because Uri is the most convenient way of expressing the address of the content. By looking at the scheme of the Uri, I get an idea on where is the information location. ex. if scheme is `http/https` I know its from the web, `file` - I know it is in my device etc,

Answer (score 0):

Using Uri will ease your work sometimes, where you want to id. your fragment by `category/subcategory/subsub/anumber` , no other reasons IMO. (Take an example of contentprovider implementation)